# Alpha-Beta Pruning: Sorting nodes

Tags: python, optimization, minimax

I'm creating a connect-four AI. I'm having issues with alpha-beta pruning optimization. Wikipedia says that sorting the nodes so that we try the most likely ones first (ie, those most likely to force an alpha/beta cutoff) will improve performance without changing the results. Here's my code without sorting. It seems to work fine.

```
def minimax_i(board, start_depth):
    """Return the highest valued move by minimaxing."""
    best_value = -100000
    best_move = None
    alpha = -100000
    beta = 100000
    moves = board.get_valid_moves()
    for move in moves:
        value = minimax_r(board.make_move(move), board.nextplayer, alpha, beta, start_depth)
        if value > best_value:
            best_value = value
            best_move = move
        if alpha >= beta:
            break
    return best_move

def minimax_r(board, player, alpha, beta, depth):
    result = board.winner()
    if result != -1: # If game is finished
        if result == 0:
            return 0
        if result == player:
            return 1000 + depth
        return -(1000 + depth)
    if depth <= 0:
        return heuristic(board, player)

    moves = board.get_valid_moves()
    if board.nextplayer == player: # Maximizing
        best_value = -100000
        for move in moves:
            score = minimax_r(board.make_move(move), player, alpha, beta, depth-1)
            best_value = max(best_value, score)
            alpha = max(alpha, best_value)
            if alpha >= beta:
                break
        return best_value

    else: # Minimizing
        best_value = 100000
        for move in moves:
            score = minimax_r(board.make_move(move), player, alpha, beta, depth-1)
            best_value = min(best_value, score)
            beta = min(beta, best_value)
            if alpha >= beta:
                break
        return best_value
```

Changing `moves = board.get_valid_moves()` to `moves = sorted(board.get_valid_moves(), key = lambda x: abs(board.lastmove[0]-x))` *should* cause it to check moves that border the last move first, a naive but hopefully useful ordering heuristic. The issue is that it changes the search results.

The only thing I can think of is that I should be propagating changes to alpha and beta that occur in child nodes back up to parent nodes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to identify your problem for sure, but I can give you some  insights that will help you. First off, you wrote:

> The only thing I can think of is that I should be propagating changes to alpha and beta that occur in child nodes back up to parent nodes. Any ideas?

This is incorrect. The intuition behind alpha-beta pruning is that if this branch will never be reached because an earlier node will not chose it, prune this branch. Alpha and beta are the bounds of the best moves earlier nodes have found. Propagating alpha and beta back up the tree would make no sense. If thus is still unclear to you I suggest making sure you have a firm grasp on the algorithm before you move on.

Now, as to what your problem is: There is a slight inaccuracy in your assumption, but it makes a very large difference. You wrote:

> Wikipedia says that sorting the nodes so that we try the most likely ones first (ie, those most likely to force an alpha/beta cutoff) will improve performance without changing the results.

This is mostly true, but not completely, although Wikipedia does say it. Alpha-beta pruning will not change the value of the result. That means that if regular minimax says move x is worth 5 according to the heuristic evaluation function you are using, alpha-beta pruning will return that as well. However, if two moves are of equal value, that is neither one is better than the other, it is normal for alpha-beta pruning to return a different move, as the change in move ordering can lead to one move being seen first.

So check. is this returning a different move of equal value, but still evaluating all moves to be of the same value as minimax? This is normal. Is it causing moves to actually be evaluated differenly? This is a serious error.

If you find the latter to be true, it is likely caused by your move ordering unintentionally omitting moves from the list. Another possible cause would be an improper implementation of the algorithm, but from your code it seems to be fine.